# Understanding proof of "linear dependence of functions $f_1, f_2,...,f_n$ implies Wronskian of these functions is identically zero

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, independence, wronskian

The proof is shown in below picture.
[image: proof]

I am not able to understand the underlined part. How author concluded that, "linear dependence of $f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ implies that the linear system in equation (10) has nontrivial solution. Please help

Comment: $(k_1, k_2, \dots, k_n)^T$ is a solution of the linear system by definition of matrix product and matrix equality. It is non trivial as by the initial hypothesis, the $k_i$ are not all zero.

Comment: They just mean that the system has a solution where not all of the $k_i$ are zero, which is relevant for the invertible matrix theorem

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sir, Thank you. Got it.